# how to alter text of ion-label

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I have a Directive that should append a string to an ion-label element.

```
/**
 * icon used everywhere to indicate this is a required form field
 * usage: <ion-label required> blah </ion-label>
 * outputs: <ion-label required> blah <span>*</span> </ion-label>
 */
@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-label[required]',
})
export class ReqIconComponent {

  constructor( el: ElementRef) {
    debugger;
    el.nativeElement.innerHTML = el.nativeElement.innerHTML.concat('<span> * </span>');
  }

}
```

How do I access the "blah" text value within the ion-label Element?

innerHTML and innerText are both "".
childNodes and children are both length 0.

Comment: The results for above is <ion-label ...> <span> * </span> blah </ion-label>

Comment: Try to move your code to ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Thanks - that works. Create an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in constructor, the view is not rendered so you can not get `innerHTML`. Move code to `ngAfterViewInit` to wait the view fully rendered.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML.concat('<span> * </span>');
}
```